# ASP.net mvc 2 routing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

```
class HomeController
{
    public ActionResult Search(int[] sections, int categories)
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

i need url like

> website.com/search/1,2,3/5

What route map should i use?

At present RegisterRoutes looks

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
            );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use something like:

```
var ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

var result = string.Join(",", ints.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());

to build the commaseparated string, and pass it in the route "Search/{csv}/{somevalue}"

Comment: And you need to add a new routes.MapRoute and place it over the default one to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the controller definition to handle the array:

```
    public ActionResult Search(string sections, int categories)
{
   // sectionsArray is int[].
   var sectionsArray = sections.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
   return View();
}
```

then you can define the routing as usual: `Home/{sections}/{categories}`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search", // Route name
    "{Home}/{sections}/{categories}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Search" } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Notice that you have to add this on top of the default one.

Comment: @Robert: I've put home as the controller based on mola10's question. He has defined Search method in `class HomeController`

Comment: I'm talking about this *Home*: `"{Home}/{sections}/{categories}"` which sets home as a URL parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### Add search route, don't replace default one

Since you'll probably still be using default route with controller/action combination I suggest you do this:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
      routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

      routes.MapRoute(
            "Search",
            "search/{sections}/{section}", // rename these variables to what they actually are
            new { controller = "Search", action = "Sections", sections = UrlParameter.Optional, section = UrlParameter.Optinal } 
      );

      routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
      );
}
```

But since it's hard to tell what requirements you're after here, maybe you're trying to use catch-all route parameter but not at the end of your URL request. If that's the case, you can [check my code in blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html) of such Route class that allows catch-all section anywhere in the URL and not just at the end as it is by default.